# Spring Data Neo4j load balancing

Tags: neo4j, load-balancing, spring-data-neo4j

I'm working on an application using Spring Data Neo4j that works with an embedded Neo4j Server. I would like for my application to be able to work with a cluster containing 3 Neo4j nodes, one of this nodes being the embedded server.

I am trying to accomplish some sort of load balancing within the cluster: 1. round-robin requests on each server or 2. write requests on the master embedded server and read requests on the other two servers.

Does Spring Data Neo4j have any kind of load balancing mechanism out of the box? What configuration is necessary to achieve this? Do I need additional tools like HAProxy or mod_proxy? Is there any example of how they can be integrated with the Neo4j cluster and Spring Data Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A load balancer component is not part of Neo4j nor part of Spring Data Neo4j. For a sample setup using Neo4j as server is documented at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-haproxy.html.

Since your application uses SDN in embedded HA mode, you need to expose the status of your local instance (master or slave) yourself to achieve the same like /db/manage/server/ha/master does in server mode. You might use [`HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.isMaster()`](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-ha/stable/apidocs/org/neo4j/kernel/ha/HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.html) in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was afraid that was the case. What I haven't yet discovered is how exactly should I configure Spring Data Neo4j to connect to the HAProxy. Shoud I use SpringRestGraphDatabase?

Comment: No, you should not use SpringRestGraphDatabase. Currently SDN performs not reasonable well in remote mode. Best practice is to use it in embedded HA mode. Unfortunately I don't have an example for this right at hand.

Comment: OK, but if I use the HA configuration mode, I'm guessing I should specify all 3 server IPs. Then how exactly is the HAProxy hit?